# Is the original PhD certificate required for a post-doctoral position in Germany?

Tags: postdocs, job, germany, certification

I am online applying for a postdoctoral position in Germany. I have the electrical copy of my PhD certificate, and that is sufficient for my application. But the original copy of the certificate is in my home country, and I am sure I cannot travel to my home country for some years. If my application was successful, would they ask for the original copy of my certificate?

I asked them by Email and I haven't received an answer yet. But the deadline is close.

Comment: I studied in Germany for my PhD. I think the answer may depend on the institution, but if I had to guess originals are not systematically required. Maybe a more knowledgeable person will say I'm wrong. Perhaps you can request a duplicate PhD certificate from your institution to be sent by mail to you.

Comment: By any chance, is your reason for not travelling home because your country is experiencing significant conflict or because your life would be in danger if you did? If so, even if you normally would need your actual certificate, these might count as exceptional circumstances. In the UK I could use an electronic copy when I applied, but was required to bring the actual certificate to HR after I was hired. You might find the same.

Comment: Do you have somebody who could send you this document, just in case?

Comment: In Germany, an original or a notary-approved copy is often required. However, increasingly, electronic documents are being accepted provisionally.

Comment: @Heutl I am not sure if I can find anyone.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Is a paper copy of notary-approved certificate required, or an electrical copy of notary-approved certificate is enough? And, are you saying based on personal experience?

Comment: @Learner Yes, based on personal experience. I have even had to produce multiple sets of hand-signed, stamped and sealed references for people just applying to German universities, including some reserve copies in case they will have multiple applications. You will have to find out from your target institution how critical this is in your case, and whether there are other ways of verifying your identity.